# Translation and scaling in GLTF

Tags: python, gltf

I am trying to display multiple boxes (with different sizes and positions) via gltf.

I am using the https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/Box/glTF/Box.gltf sample as a template and simply replace the nodes with new nodes.

When I create my nodes as

```
 gltf["scenes"][0]["nodes"]=[]
 gltf["nodes"]=[]
 nodeId=0
 for x, y, z, w, h, d in boxes: 
    gltf["nodes"]+=[{ "mesh": 0, "translation": [x, y, z], "scale":[w, h, d]}]
    gltf["scenes"][0]["nodes"]+=[nodeId]
    nodeId+=1
```

the boxes (which are next to each other) collide (not only on the edges). So the 3d is wrong.

When I create my boxes without scaling (from a lot of small boxes), it works:

```
 gltf["scenes"][0]["nodes"]=[]
 gltf["nodes"]=[]
 nodeId=0
 for x, y, z, w, h, d in boxes: 
    for x1 in range(x, w+w):
        for y1 in range(y, y+w):
            for z1 in range(z, z+d):
                gltf["nodes"]+=[{"mesh": 0, "translation": [x1, y1, z1]}] 
                gltf["scences"][0]["nodes"]+=[nodeId]
                nodeId+=1
```

But this of course a much bigger and complex gltf.

The coordinates in boxes is the lower left front corner  (minimum of x, y, and z values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glTF sample box you linked to has vertex positions ranging from `-0.5` to `0.5` along each axis.  So to position a box, you should translate the node to where the center of the box will be.

I haven't tried running this code, but for `x, y, z` values that represent corners of boxes, something like the following should change it to be the centers of boxes.  The only change I've made is to add half the width, half the height, and half the depth to the translation.

```
 gltf["scenes"][0]["nodes"]=[]
 gltf["nodes"]=[]
 nodeId=0
 for x, y, z, w, h, d in boxes: 
    gltf["nodes"]+=[{ "mesh": 0, "translation": [
       x + w/2,
       y + h/2,
       z + d/2
       ], "scale":[w, h, d]}]
    gltf["scenes"][0]["nodes"]+=[nodeId]
    nodeId+=1
```